# AbstractHttpControllerTestCase testing AbstractRestfulController

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am having trouble with `AbstractRestfulController` unit tests. I am trying to test post action. I am using `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase` to test my controller. Everything works fine with getList action. I am using `$this->dispatch('/api/login');` to call it. But then I am trying to test create action with

```
$data = array('ip' => true);
$this->dispatch('/api/login', 'POST', $data);
```

I am getting route no match error. What am I doing wrong? Will I be able to test PUT and DELETE actions?

Maybe i should unit test restful API using different technique?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project, it helped me realize I was doing some setup incorrectly for my own Zend Framework 2 based Restful Controller :

https://github.com/RichardKnop/zend-v2-skeleton

As for the POST question, check this particular source out :

`~zend-v2-skeleton/tests/module/Api/src/Api/Controller/ResourceControllerTest.php`

```
public function testCreateHttpStatusCode()
{
    $this->_request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
    $this->_controller->dispatch($this->_request, $this->_response);
    $this->assertEquals(201, $this->_response->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer. I have built something similar to this solution, but I want to know is it possible to use `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase`